# How to access virtual machines started with QEMU?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, xen

I wish I could connect to virtual machines started with QEMU.

Then I should extract the information about the registers (EIP, EBP, etc.)

In XEN for this, there is the function `get_vcpu_context`, also there are other functions through which you can connect to each virtual machine separately.

Is there any such support for QEMU, and where can I find QEMU hypercalls documentation?

Comment: You can ssh into the virtual machine if you passed in a network argument when loading the VM.

Comment: I know this, but I want to get the status of vcpu at a certain frequency. I need to write a C program to call some API from QEMU, but I don't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- you can connect to the QEMU gdbstub and use the GDB remote protocol to query CPU state. This is probably the most reliable method.
- you can connect to the QEMU monitor and use the "info registers" command. Note that the output format of this might change between QEMU releases, though (it is intended for human consumption, not other programs), so it will be less reliable long-term than using GDB remote protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for something more independent.
I want to write a C program to list all virtual machines started with qemu and get their status.

Comment: QEMU doesn't maintain a list of virtual machines at all -- it is just the program that runs one VM. If you use a "management layer" program like libvirt it will have APIs or command line programs to query the VMs it manages.